# sending massage from Background script to content script in onCreated event chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sendmessage, content-script

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    var newObj = tabsArray.find((obj) => obj.id === tabs.id);
    if (!newObj) {
      tabsArray.push({
        id: tabs[0].id,
        url: tabs[0].url,
        title: tabs[0].title,
      });
    }
    console.log(tabsArray);
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { tabsArray: tabsArray }, {}, function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

contentScript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.tabsArray) {
    console.log(message.tabsArray);
  }
});
```

for manifest v3.i am trying to send this tabsArray to content script but it's not working it's shows an error like this "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.".

Comment: It works if you reverse the direction. Send a message from the content script to the service worker, and process the service worker's response in the content script.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but can't find a solution.